Получение информации о бизнесе/культурных объектах на карте
Есть ли метод в апи карт для получения информации о существующих/интерактивных объектах на карте? Это бизнесы, культурные объекты. Они интерактивны, но если подписаться на клики карты map.events.add('click'), то при клике на эти маркеры событие клика не срабатывает. А в миллиметре от этого маркера - срабатывает. Думал, через полученные координаты хотя-бы через геокодинг найти бизнес, но пока не пойму какое событие надо использовать. В гугл картах есть удобное апи Places, там сразу вся инфа отдается о кликнутом объекте, который отдает провайдер, а в Яндексе ничего подобного я не нашел.

В API Яндекс Карт есть похожее API — Поиск по организациям. Сервис поиска по организациям предназначен для поиска географических объектов (топонимов) и организаций. Сервис позволяет искать дома, улицы, достопримечательности, кафе и другие объекты.
